# Find the coefficient of $x^{15}$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, generating-functions

How do you find the coefficient of $x^{15}$ from $x^{3}$$(1-2x)^{10}$? Thank you.

Comment: I think 13 is the highest degree of this expression?

Comment: but in general you can use a binomial expansion $(1-2x)^{10}=\sum_{i=1}^{10}\binom{10}{i}(-2x)^{i}1^{10-i}$.

Answer (score 3):

The coefficient of $x^{15}$ from $\displaystyle x^3(1−2x)^{10}$

$=$ the coefficient of $\displaystyle x^{15-3}$ from $\displaystyle(1−2x)^{10}$

Now the $r$th term of $\displaystyle(1−2x)^{10}$ is $\displaystyle\binom{10}r(1)^{10-r}(-2x)^r$

Clearly, we need $r=12$

Now, $\displaystyle\binom{10}{12}=?$